# android developing with Facebook SDK. (Invalid key hash)

Tags: java, android, facebook, key, facebook-android-sdk

I am working in a team and we are developing an app which integrates the Facebook SDK.

When I try to test the app I get: Invalid key hash. Only the original developer can test it, as the Key hash was generated in his PC.

Is there a away to work with multiple developer using FB sdk and get around the key hash ?

Comment: Generate a keyhash for your machine and add it at the Dev console in FB. You can add multipe keyhashes. Also make sure that you are listed as a dev in the console so that you can use your email id to test.

Comment: does it means, that everyone in the team has to add their pc key hash to facebook console ?

Comment: Yes - everyone who is developing on different machines.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a keyhash for your machine and add it at the Dev console in FB. You can add multipe keyhashes. Also make sure that you are listed as a dev in the console so that you can use your email id to test.

You will also have to take care of the .apk signing key across machines. Key hash will change if the Debug key hash or the release key hash changes.

[***From the docs: You can add multiple key hashes if you develop with multiple machines.***](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Your team have to use only ONE developer key (the same key for every teammate) for app signing.